# c# Quartz.NET injected IServiceProvider is always disposed

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, quartz.net

I have an application in .NET 7 that is supposed to use Quartz to run scheduled jobs. The problem is that if I try to use the DI and the `IServiceProvider` interface, I always get an exception indicating that the object has been disposed. In the beginning I used the Microsoft `BackgrouService` and everything worked fine, as soon as I switched to the `IJob` interface I started having this kind of errors.
This is my job class:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
public class EventHubLogProcessorJob : IJob
{
    // Omit some code for brevity

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<ClientEvent> _clientEvents = new();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _eventsPerPartition = new();

    private readonly ILogger<EventHubLogProcessorJob> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public EventHubLogProcessorJob(ILogger<EventHubLogProcessorJob> logger,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(logger);
        Guard.Against.Null(serviceProvider);

        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(StorageConnectionString, BlobContainerName);

            var processor = new EventProcessorClient(
                storageClient, ConsumerGroup, EventHubConnectionString, EventProcessorClientOptions);

            processor.ProcessEventAsync += OnProcessEvent;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += OnProcessError;

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync(context.CancellationToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "Task was canceled");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "An unhandled exception has occurred");
        }
    }


    private Task OnProcessError(ProcessErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {
        _logger.LogError(errorEventArgs.Exception, "OnProcess error");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (eventArgs.Data?.EventBody is null ||
                eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToString().Contains(Constants.EventType.Failure))
            {
                return;
            }

            var logAudit = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogAuditRoot>(eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToString(),
                SerializerOptions);

            if (logAudit.Tags.Contains(Constants.Tag.Stage, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }
            
            var clientEvent = logAudit.ClientEvent;

            if (clientEvent.ClientId == Guid.Empty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientEvent.ClientName))
            {
                return;
            }

            _clientEvents.Enqueue(clientEvent);

            var partitionId = eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId;

            // Initialize or increment the count for the current partition. 
            if (!_eventsPerPartition.TryAdd(partitionId, 0))
            {
                ++_eventsPerPartition[partitionId];
            }

            if (_eventsPerPartition[partitionId] >= 100)
            {
                await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await InsertDataIntoDatabaseAsync();

                _clientEvents.Clear();
                _eventsPerPartition[partitionId] = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "ProcessEventHandler exception");
        }
    }

    private async Task InsertDataIntoDatabaseAsync()
    {
        // Here i get the exception that the object has been disposed
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var repository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();
        
        _logger.LogInformation("Count: {Count}", _clientEvents.Count.ToString());

        foreach (var clientEvent in _clientEvents)
        {
            var activity = clientEvent.ToEntity();

            repository.Insert(activity);

            await repository.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope(IServiceProvider provider)

This is the code where I configure Quartz:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options => { options.ServiceName = "ClientLogProcessor"; })
    .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
            .ReadFrom.Services(services)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog())
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        var environment = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;

        builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json");
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddWindowsService();
        services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
        });

        //services.AddHostedService<EventHubLogProcessorJob>();


        services.AddQuartz(configurator =>
        {
            configurator.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
        
            const string eventHubJobKey = nameof(EventHubLogProcessorJob);
        
            configurator.AddJob<EventHubLogProcessorJob>(options => options.WithIdentity(eventHubJobKey));
            
            configurator.AddTrigger(options => options.ForJob(eventHubJobKey).StartNow());
        });
        
        services.AddQuartzHostedService();
    })
    .Build();
```

How come this problem occurs with Quartz, while if I implement the Microsoft BackgrouService not?
How can I fix this? I hope I was clear.
A thousand thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the problem is that I have to listen to that event for the entire duration on which I set the job, for example: 
.WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(scheduler =>
scheduler.OnEveryDay() .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(10,30)).EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(16, 30))));
So if I understand correctly it is not possible?

Comment: Reading other problems similar to mine I tried to use `IServiceScopeFactory` instead of `IServiceProvider` and now it seems to work with Quartz too.